# Do I need a preposition in structures 'leaves smth someone?'

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality-in-context

What preposition (if any) would you put in the following sentence?

> This leaves (to/for/-) ethnic minorities little room to dissent,
> especially (to/for/-) those who also experience financial problems.

Answer (score 3):

No, as written, the sentence needs no additional words. But if worded differently, it would need a preposition:

This leaves little room for ethnic minorities to dissent...

Another option would put the subordinate clause in the middle:

This leaves ethnic minorities, especially those who also experience financial problems, little room to dissent.
(You could add "with" before "little", but it's not wrong without it.)

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated than it looks. Your first sentence is fine, but it's not as easy as I thought it was to explain this.

In similar sentences with an object and a recipient, *leave* is ditransitive, like *give* and *show*, so the indirect object can either come after the direct object, with a preposition:

> I gave/showed the book to him.

> I left the book for/with him

or it can come before the direct object, with no preposition.

> I gave/showed him the book.

> I left him the book.

(The difference between *with* and *for* here is whether he had it when I left it ('with') or would receive it later ('for'). *Leave something **to** somebody* is used only in special meanings: either *bequeath* (as in, "leave something in one's will") or in the case of a problem or task, *pass on the responsibility* for the problem or task.)

However, here there is not a direct and an indirect object, but a single object, *little room for ethnic minorities to dissent* (I'm leaving out the extra clause for the moment). This consists of a Noun Phrase *little room* with a complement consisting of the infinitive clause *for ethnic minorities to dissent*. Like most infinitive clauses, the complement of *room* requires *for* if the subject is explicit: "room to expand" vs "room for them to expand".

But what your example does is to raise the NP *ethnic minorities* out of the clause and out of the direct object, into an independent indirect object:

> leave [little room [[for ethnic minorities] to dissent]] -> leave [little room [to dissent]] [for ethnic minorities]

and then use the ditransitive rearrangement I described above, to bring the new indirect object before the direct object:

> leave [little room [to dissent]] [for ethnic minorities] -> leave [ethnic minorities] [little room [to dissent]].

(I'm not convinced that the middle step in that derivation is actually grammatical. It's certainly awkward).

I've not thought about this question before: there may be a different and more general analysis in the grammar books.